# chmod not working on USB drive on Raspberry PI

Tags: raspbian, usb, mount, ntfs

I'm trying to share WD 2TB USB drive connected to a new Raspberry PI.

Running on Raspbian Jessie version 4.1, USB drive mounts automatically. This isn't a problem, but it's not accessible from my Windows 7 computer.

```
ntfs-3 is already installed and up to date.
```

I'm not able to change permissions for files on my USB drive:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/media/pi/WD_2TB/temp $ sudo chmod -v 777 tst2
mode of ‘tst2’ changed from 0600 (rw-------) to 0777 (rwxrwxrwx)
pi@raspberrypi:/media/pi/WD_2TB/temp $ ls -l
total 0
-rw------- 1 pi pi 0 Mar  2 01:34 tst2
pi@raspberrypi:/media/pi/WD_2TB/temp $
```

Just in case, here is part from my smb.conf:

```
[WD_2TB]
comment = Backup Folder
path = /media/pi/WD_2TB
writeable = Yes
readonly = No
public = Yes
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
browseable = Yes
public = yes
guest = OK
```

Comment: What file system is being used?  I doubt a Windows formatted disk would recognise Linux permissions.

Comment: this is NTFS disk. Apparently ntfs-3g should be able to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

NTFS is file system designed by Microsoft that is primarily used by Windows systems. `chmod` changes the **linux** permissions on a file. The two are not compatible.

Your `cmb.conf` file looks correct. My assumption is that you aren't specifying a user/group in the mounting step.

Comment: Thank you Jacobm001 for quick answer.
There is no "mounting/step" on my part. It's automatic.